# Autowire a Method with Different Parameters Based on Active Profile

Tags: java, spring

With Spring Boot, I have an autowired method and if the active profile is local I want to pass in two variables to from the properties file, but if it's dev/prod I want to pass in just one variable (the endpoint isn't required due to the auto configuration of the environment).

This doesn't work because spring doesn't know which method to autowire. I've played around with adding (required=true/false) and it still throws errors no matter how I configure required. Is there a better way to add an optional profile-based parameter value?

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
application-local.properties

company.group.endpoint=http://localhost:8000/
company.group.version=/v2
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
application-dev.properties

company.group.version=/v3
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*/

// Worker.java

@Component
public class Worker {
    private String endpoint;
    private String version;

    @Autowired
    public Worker(@Value("${company.group.version}") String version) {
        this.version = version;
        // do work
    }

    @Autowired
    public Worker(@Value("${company.group.version}") String version, 
                  @Value("${company.group.endpoint}") String endpoint) {
        this.version = version;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        // do work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading constructors with injectable beans is not as straight as with pojo classes.
Indeed Spring doesn't know which constructor should be invoked.

So as alternative favor the use of a single autowired constructor.
You could make one of the parameters optional by specifying a default value such as `null` :

```
@Autowired
public Worker(@Value("${company.group.version}") String version, 
              @Value("${company.group.endpoint:#{null}}") String endpoint) {
    this.version = version;
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    // do work
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It looks like specifying the Autowired value in the constructor doesn't mean the property has to exist, if you set it to default to null like you pointed out, the profiles that don't declare it just default to null and work, you're just responsible for handling the logic for what to do when the property is null.

Answer (score 1):

Use only *one* constructor, and move the optional parameter to a field.  By convention, you separate out what parameters are mandatory for this component to exist, and what are optional, making your code a bit easier to test and maintain.

```
@Component
public class Worker {
    @Value("${company.group.endpoint:@null}")
    private String endpoint;
    private String version;

    @Autowired
    public Worker(@Value("${company.group.version}") String version) {
        this.version = version;
        // do work
    }
}
```